# Gitlab Multi Runner

Tags: gitlab, runner

I have just installed gitlab runner by using tutorial from their website. I would like to know if this installation that I used is running with multiple runner feature. I have these installed:

1. Gitlab-runner
2. Gitlab-ci-multi-runner

I have checked both of them can run multi runner from both --help docs.
Also, running `gitlab-runner verify` showed me 2 runner that I have registered before to my different repo. Here is the sample:

[image]

Does it means that I have 2 different runner ? and run async ?

Thank you, I am new on setting up this kind of things hahaha

Answer (score 3):

I vaguely remember there being a *historical* difference, but having just [installed from the official repo](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html), `gitlab-ci-multi-runner` is now a symlink to `gitlab-runner`:

```
[ltheisen@pd-ci ~]$ ls -al /usr/bin | grep gitlab | grep runner
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root          13 Sep 20 19:07 gitlab-ci-multi-runner -> gitlab-runner
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    50570231 Sep 20 19:07 gitlab-runner
```

Answer (score 0):

That output from verify shows that you are running two runners. My take on the documentation is that multi-runner what starts multiple instances of gitlab-runner.

It was very helpful to me to run gitlab-runner interactively (`gitlab-runner run`), so that I could see the output in the console. Once I got my config.toml the way I wanted it (and without error) I could just run `gitlab-runner run`.